# project deployment to zeit reads "warning project is missing a now.json file with version ###"

Tags: node.js, vercel

when deploying my project up to my zeit clipboard,  after the success deployment a warning sign appears stating "your project is missing a now.json file with version ###". then i went to the zeit website to get the new version for now but it doesnt work. byt the way It's a node project. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest version won't resolve this warning. Having the `now.json` files allows you to specify options. Zeit added support for additional options, these can be specified in the `now.json` file. It looks something like this

```
{
    "version": 2.2, 
    "builds": [
        { "src": "*.js", "use": "@now/node" }
    ]
}
```

Note: You can still deploy to Zeit without a `now.json` file. However, if your project has no `now.json` file, or has one but no builds property defined, the projects source* files will be deployed directly as the output.

- Learn more about `now.json` and what available options exist [here](https://zeit.co/blog/now-json)
- Learn more about sources and outputs [here](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/builds/#sources-and-outputs)

**Sources* are files that already exist in your project before deploying and can be used to define the output